# StreamReader in class for SqlConnection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

I have this code in class which should read 4 lines from textbox but the program stops so I don't know where the error is. I think Im not on a bad way but I need to little improve it.

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

namespace tours
{
   class myConnection
   {
       public static SqlConnection GetConnection()
       {
            string path = "C:\\Users\\marek\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\tours\\tours\\sql_string.txt";

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open));

            while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
            {
            }

            string str = "Data Source='" + sr.ReadLine() + "';Initial Catalog ='" + sr.ReadLine() + "' ;user='" + sr.ReadLine() + "';password= '" + sr.ReadLine() + "'";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
            con.Open();
            return con;
       }
    }
}
```

This is how I call it in form

```
private void nastaveni_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        try
        {
            nacti_spojeni();
            myConnection.GetConnection();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the

```
//while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
//{

//}
string str = "Data Source='" + sr.ReadLine() + "';Initial Catalog ='" + sr.ReadLine() + "' ;user='" + sr.ReadLine() + "';password= '" + sr.ReadLine() + "'";
```

Or you can do as below

```
var lines =  File.ReadAllLines(path);
if (lines.Length >=4)
{
    string str = string.Format("Data Source='{0}';Initial Catalog ='{1}' ;user='{2}';password= '{3}'"
        , lines[0], lines[1], lines[2], lines[3]);
}
```

I'm not sure why you save connection details on text file. in .Net we can store connection string in web.config if it is web application or otherwise app config file

Read more about this please check below links:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/store-connection-string-in-webconfig/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: May I ask you how should I call this method from another form for SqlCommand/SqlDataAdapter like this ? SqlDataAdapter SDA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM zajezd", myConnection.GetConnection());